# Laravel Type Error:Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save() must be an instance

Tags: laravel

**Full Error:**

```
TypeError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, null given, called in F:\php\phpcourse\website\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php on line 75
```

I am trying to assign a `guest` role to the user when the user registers the account, seeing  [attach role to a user upon registration laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961291/attach-role-to-a-user-upon-registration-laravel-5-4)

But I faced this error. So I don't know how to solve this rid because I am beginner at Laravel.

Here is my code

**User model**

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Role')->withPivot('role_id');
    }
```

**RegisterController**

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $role = \App\Models\Role::where('name', 'guest')->first();
        $user =  User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'is_active' => 1, // add new
        ]);
        $user->roles()->save($role);
        return $user;
    }
```

Comment: Check if your roles table has a record with the name 'guest'

Comment: `first` can return `null`, so there is no Role with that 'name' apparently

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem in the code, just confirm you have guest role in roles table

```
$role = \App\Models\Role::where('name', 'guest')->first();
```

first() can return null if no record found